# print string with colours under windows

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

I am wondering whatever it is possible to output string with colour in assembly program ran on cmd. What I have in mind is similar thing to 0x02 graphics mode under DOS, where you can write message as following:

```
message db 'H', 0x0f, 'e', 0x04, 'l', 0x01, 'l', 0x05, 'o', 0x07 ;etc
```

In this case each letter would be with different foreground on different background. Is the same possible in windows console?

---

I have no idea how to word this question better, feel free to improve it or ask further details in comments

Comment: VT100-like escape sequences work in W10, do you need to support anything older?

Comment: Well I am trying to get it working on windows 7 and higher

Comment: `SetConsoleTextAttribute` and `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` then

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions for complete current API (not sure how to filter out between win7/win10, I don't use windows at all)